# how to exclude logs/events in journalbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, typhoon-kubernetes

We are using journalbeat to push logs of kubernetes cluster to elastic search. It working fine and pushing the logs. However its also pushing event like "200 OK" and "INFO" which we do not want. The `journalbeat.yaml` is as follows

#### journalbeat.yaml

```yaml
  journalbeat.yml: |
    name: "${NODENAME}"
    journalbeat.inputs:
    - paths: []
      seek: cursor
      cursor_seek_fallback: tail

    processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        host: "${NODENAME}"
        in_cluster: true
        default_indexers.enabled: false
        default_matchers.enabled: false
        indexers:
          - container:
        matchers:
          - fields:
              lookup_fields: ["container.id"]
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        process_array: false
        max_depth: 1
        target: ""
        overwrite_keys: true
    - drop_event.when:
        or:
        - regexp.kubernetes.pod.name: "filebeat-.*"
        - regexp.kubernetes.pod.name: "journalbeat-.*"
        - regexp.kubernetes.pod.name: "nginx-ingress-controller-.*"
        - regexp.kubernetes.pod.name: "prometheus-operator-.*"

    setup.template.enabled: false
    setup.template.name: "journal-${ENVIRONMENT}-%{[agent.version]}"
    setup.template.pattern: "journal-${ENVIRONMENT}-%{[agent.version]}-*"
    setup.template.settings:
      index.number_of_shards: 10
      index.refresh_interval: 10s

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:elasticsearch:9200}'
      username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
      password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
      index: "journal-${ENVIRONMENT}-system-%{[agent.version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      indices:
      - index: "journal-${ENVIRONMENT}-k8s-%{[agent.version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        when.has_fields:
        - 'kubernetes.namespace'
```

How can i exclude logs like "INFO" and "200 OK" events?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to exclude logs in [Journalbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/current/index.html). It's working other way around, meaning you tell it what input to look for.
You should read about [Configuration input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/master/configuration-journalbeat-options.html#configuration-journalbeat-options):

> By default, Journalbeat reads log events from the default systemd journals. To specify other journal files, set the [`paths`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/master/configuration-journalbeat-options.html#journalbeat-paths) option in the `journalbeat.inputs` section of the `journalbeat.yml` file. Each path can be a directory path (to collect events from all journals in a directory), or a file path.

```
journalbeat.inputs:
- paths:
  - "/dev/log"
  - "/var/log/messages/my-journal-file.journal"
```

> Within the configuration file, you can also specify options that control how Journalbeat reads the journal files and which fields are sent to the configured output. See Configuration options for a list of available options.

Get familiar with the [Configuration options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/master/configuration-journalbeat-options.html#journalbeat-options) and using the [translated fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/master/configuration-journalbeat-options.html#translated-fields) to target the exact input you want to.

```
{beatname_lc}.inputs:
- id: consul.service
  paths: []
  include_matches:
    - _SYSTEMD_UNIT=consul.service

- id: vault.service
  paths: []
  include_matches:
    - _SYSTEMD_UNIT=vault.service
```

You should use it to target the inputs you want to have pushed to elastic.

As an alternative to [Journalbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/current/index.html) you could use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat) and the exclude might look like this:

```
type: log
paths:
{{ range $i, $path := .paths }}
 - {{$path}}
{{ end }}
exclude_files: [".gz$"]
exclude_lines: ['.*INFO.*']
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Crou, have you tried this regex `regexp.kubernetes.pod.name: "prometheus-operator-.*"` which i gave in the yaml file above. I observed yesterday that it drops event based on the regex i provide. So i can drop event with regex like `regexp.message: .*HTTP 1.1 200.*`, the regex may not be complete but i hope you get the idea. Its working but i am not sure how. I am planning to test it on GCP and upload to github. I read the docs and found what you are saying is correct. They don't support exclude. But i do not know how its working. Any thoughts ? :) ... thanks again.

Comment: if you get time you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550249/journalbeat-is-not-shipping-logs-to-elasticsearch-or-not-outputting-logs-on-cons), i had to make some changes for SELinux disabling and volume monunts change to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

To apply filter use:

```
logging.level: warning
```

Use this instruction to drop event `journalbeat.service`:

```
processors:
  - drop_event:
      when:
        equals:
          systemd.unit: "journalbeat.service"
```

Comment: Thanks @Antonio, yeah we tried these already and now its working.

Comment: No problem. This configuration is only on GNU/Linux OS. Take care with your disk consumption and processor. You can check these metrics with Grafana or other software of monitoring.